# Understanding the voxel grid implementation of pcl library

Tags: computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, voxel

I have a point cloud data(x,y,z), I want to voxelize this point cloud and get all the voxels. PCL voxelgrid implementation voxelizes the point cloud and return the centroid of each voxel. Exact implementation of voxel grid is in the url 'http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/voxel__grid_8hpp_source.html#l00214'. Any other references for voxelizing the point cloud is also appreciable.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I have a point cloud (x,y,z). I need to voxelize this point cloud and return all the voxels. Say for example you have got 40 voxels, each voxel should contain 
 some minimum number of points. PCL library voxelizes the point cloud but it returns the centroids of each voxel, I need all voxels and the points belong to each voxel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`OctreePointCloudPointVector`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_point_cloud_point_vector.html) for that exact use-case.

Each leaf is a [`OctreeContainerPointIndices`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_container_point_indices.html), where you can get all points inside that leaf with [`getPointIndicesVector`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_container_point_indices.html#a5ae042c100615a4ddc6f3016c88c25e9).

Have a look at [`test_octree.cpp`](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/test/octree/test_octree.cpp) how to use `Octree` classes in PCL.

Comment: Updated links:- `OctreePointCloudPointVector` --> https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_point_cloud_point_vector.html , `OctreeContainerPointIndices` --> https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_container_point_indices.html